# Cumulative sum based on certain column values

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

> [01/Aug/1995:00:54:59 -0400] "GET /images/opf-logo.gif HTTP/1.0" 200
>   32511 [01/Aug/1995:00:55:04 -0400] "GET /images/ksclogosmall.gif
>   HTTP/1.0" 200 4635 [01/Aug/1995:00:55:06 -0400] "GET
>   /images/ksclogosmall.gif HTTP/1.0" 403 78787

I have a file from an HTTP server and I need to list out top 10 images based on cumulative sum on size (in bytes) which is the last column.

```
li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("input.txt").readlines()]

sorted_li = sorted(li, key = lambda cols : int(cols[6]), reverse = True)

sorted_out = {}

for l in sorted_li:

    if l[3] in sorted_out:
        sorted_out[l[3]] += int(l[6])
    else:
        sorted_out[l[3]] = int(l[6])
```

How can I limit to top 10 values from the dictionary? Is there a way I can do without using pandas and group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from standard lib.

```
from collections import Counter

d = dict()
with open('input.txt') as f:
    split_line_gen = (line.strip().split() for line in f)
    get_name_size_gen = ((line[3], int(line[-1])) for line in split_line_gen)
    for name, size in get_name_size_gen:
        d[name] = d.get(name, 0) + size
    c = Counter(d)
```

To get top 10 use `c.most_common(10)`

Using of counter can be a bit overhead. Instead you can use something like

`sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)[:10]` return only names

`sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)[:10]` return names and sizes

But I would recomend to use Counter -- more readable, imo.

Comment: But, it does not do the cumulative sum as gets only top 10 records.

Comment: @paddu `sorted` returns a list and doesn't change source, so if you would to use result of sorting you need to assign it to some variable, i.e. `result = sorted ...`